# Need to have a single function to handle all CRUD operation in the database

Tags: node.js, typescript

i m trying to create a function that helps all CRUD operation in the database
by using parameter query.

how can i achieve that can some one help

```js
async function getorsetData(query:string, typeofquery:string, data?:any, inputparams?:any): Promise<any> {
    const pool:any = await SQLPOOL;
    let res:any;
    switch (typeofquery) {
        case 'SELECT':
                res = await pool.query(query);
                break;
        case 'INSERT':
               break;
        case 'UPDATE':
               break;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Why do you "*need*" that? It sounds like a strange idea.

Comment: It's usually called CRUD.

Comment: @danronmoon ya sorry my bad

Comment: @str ya it is wanted to try something